# Store only a resized version of an enormous uploaded image

Tags: media

I have editors uploading images the size of 3.8MB. I don't want to lower the maximum size for image/file upload (it's set to be 5MB), that's because I use core Image Styles (admin/config/media/image-styles), but for a server's sake, is it possible to make them upload that enormous file but just store a resized, smaller version of it? let's say, store a reduced 800x800px version of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that functionality is in Drupal core as default.

In Image field settings (your Content type -> Manage fields) set for **Maximum image resolution** to 800x800px. Drupal will resize image size and save only resized version of it.

Comment: thank you. I haven't noticed that the core functionality you mentioned was actually storing a resized image, i thought it would only reject it if the uploaded file was bigger than 800x800px.

Comment: I have uploaded a large image (5,600x4,000 pixels) from file/add but the resizing did not happen. does the resizing only occur when uploading a file from a Content Type field? How can I make the automatic resize happen from file/add?